# How to change font size in streamlit

Tags: python, html, css, streamlit

I want to change the fontsize of the label above an input widget in my streamlit app.

What I have so far:

```py
import streamlit as st
label = "Enter text here"
st.text_input(label)
```

This renders the following:
[image: text input field]

I want to make the label "Enter text here" bigger.

I know there are various ways to change fontsize in `st.write()`. So, I tried some of them:

- the markdown headers syntax:

  ```py
  st.write(f"# {label}")            # <--- works
  st.text_input(f"# {label}")       # <--- doesn't work
  ```
- some CSS:

  ```py
  s = f"<p style='font-size:20px;'>{label}</p>"
  st.markdown(s, unsafe_allow_html=True)        # <--- works
  st.text_input(s)                              # <--- doesn't work
  ```

but as commented above, neither work. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option 1: Components API

So did a little digging and it turns out that streamlit has a [components API](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api) which can be used to render an html string. So we can basically use a little javascript to change the font size of a specific label. Since labels are unique for each widget, we can simply search for the paragraph element whose inner text that matches the label.

A working example:

```py
label = "Enter text here"
st.text_input(label)

st.components.v1.html(
    f"""
    <script>
        var elems = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="stTextInput"] p');
        var elem = Array.from(elems).find(x => x.innerText == '{label}');
        elem.style.fontSize = '20px'; // the fontsize you want to set it to
    </script>
    """
)
```

It renders a field that looks like the following:

[image: img1]

A convenience function that can be used to change font size, color and font family (you can actually add more as you wish):

```py
def change_label_style(label, font_size='12px', font_color='black', font_family='sans-serif'):
    html = f"""
    <script>
        var elems = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll('p');
        var elem = Array.from(elems).find(x => x.innerText == '{label}');
        elem.style.fontSize = '{font_size}';
        elem.style.color = '{font_color}';
        elem.style.fontFamily = '{font_family}';
    </script>
    """
    st.components.v1.html(html)

label = "My text here"
st.text_input(label)
change_label_style(label, '20px')
```

---

#### Option 2: Latex text

It turns out you can use LaTeX expressions, so I ended up using latex text in math mode because you can change font size using `\Huge`, `\LARGE` etc. in Latex. Since the default font in streamlit is sans-serif, I used `\textsf{}`. A working example:

```py
import streamlit as st

st.text_input(r"$\textsf{\Large Enter text here}$")
```

which renders

[image: img1]

---

The above uses `\Large` font size. The following is an example using all possible font size options:

```py
label = r'''
$\textsf{
    \Huge Text \huge Text \LARGE Text \Large Text 
    \large Text \normalsize Text \small Text 
    \footnotesize Text \scriptsize Text \tiny Text 
}$
'''
st.text_input(label)
```

[image: img2]